# Searching for first letter in SQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Alright so I made this little script that runs and checks where some name contains character that user inputed.
So for example if I enter "A" it will show me ALL users that have "A" as part of their name (Admin, Toma) etc. etc.
Now what I want to achieve is quite simple, I want of it to select only characters that START with that letter.
So for example imagine I type in A it will display me only Admin and NOT Toma since TOMA starts with T.

Current query

```
query("SELECT ime FROM users WHERE ime LIKE '%".$term."%'")
```

Do you suggest that I use PHP to achieve this or directly do this with a query?

If so let me know what is the best way, thank you in advance!

Comment: Take off the leading `%`. That is a leading wildcard, allowing anything before. You also should use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 2):

Your query should just remove the initial wildcard:

```
"SELECT ime FROM users WHERE ime LIKE '".$term."%'"
```

Comment: Aha, so that means with the first % was actually to limit it from just selecting first letter only? Also should I just do it directly over the query (like you shown me) or maybe just do this over the PHP?

Comment: @Tommy . . . I think the documentation explains it well:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `'%'` wildcard character from the beginning of the LIKE comparison. That wildcard character matches zero, one or more of any character.

As a demonstation

```
SELECT 'Toma' LIKE '%A%'        -- contains an 'A'
     , 'Toma' LIKE 'A%'         -- starts with 'A'
     , 'Toma' LIKE 'Toma'       -- matches 'Toma'
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I love the demonstration! Thanks lad, that demonstration helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
query("SELECT ime FROM users WHERE ime LIKE '".$term."%'")
```

Just remove the the first `%`
Please check this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp for more info

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT ime FROM users WHERE ime LIKE '".$term."%'"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.